# how to clear cache using javascript when starting Offline application

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, node-webkit, appdata

I need a help to clear cache using Javascript, Is it possible to clear cache using Javascript?.

I have developed a Offline Chrome application using Javascript & Node WebKit. When using this application, the cache sizes increasing more day by day.

So I want to delete cache directory or clearing cache from AppData/Local/MyAPP.1.0 whenever I'm starting application.

Kindly help me to clear the cache using Javascript (related solution).

Please let me know, if you need any information on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add code to show your progress and help us pinpoint your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, It might works

```
require("nw.gui").App.clearCache();
```

Comment: You can just do `nw.App.clearCache();` now. The `require('nw.gui')` part was only needed on versions below 0.13.0.

Answer (score 2):

I always disable disk cache because I find it slows everything down; even in the browser I wrote, so if you want to disable it which also means that there won't be any garbage to clean up, use this setting in your **package.json**:

```
 "chromium-args": "--disk-cache-dir=W:/abc --media-cache-dir=W:/abc --disk-cache-size=1 --media-cache-size=1",
```

NB: The above are DUMMY drives/paths that don't exist to kill the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Use this recursive function to delete all files from AppData/Local/{MyAPP.1.0}/

```
deleteFolderRecursive:function(path) {        
    var fs = require("fs");
    if( fs.existsSync(path) ) {
        try{
            fs.readdirSync(path).forEach(function(file) {
                var curPath = path + "/" + file;
                if(fs.statSync(curPath).isDirectory()) { 
                    try{
                        deleteFolderRecursive(curPath);
                    }catch(e){
                        console.log(e);
                    }
                } else {
                    try{
                        fs.unlinkSync(curPath);
                    }catch(e){
                        console.log(e);
                    }
                }
            });
            fs.rmdirSync(path);
        }catch(e){
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Get AppData folder path using

```
var path = require("nw.gui").App.dataPath;
```

Get AppData folder path using

```
deleteFolderRecursive(path);
```